# git sync repository with npm package?

Tags: git, npm

So I'm trying to Fork [threejs](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) library and made some edits for my specific usage, the thing is I only need the files that in the [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/three) and not the whole git repository!

is there a way to fork only the files that exist in the NPM packages from that git? I tried to install the npm files and push them to a new repository but then I couldn't pull the updates from the upstream (the main git repository).

cloning the whole package with `depth=1` is still a nightmare because it is almost 1GB~ and growing with time.

So I was thinking of install npm files and push them to a new repository, but I'd like to keep the new repository updated whenever a new version of the npm is released (without ignoring my changes for sure)

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your question correctly. But if I do you should probably rephrase it to _How to clone/pull only a subfolder of a remote git repository_ since you're trying to pull only the [`build` directory](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build) from that repo, do you?

Comment: @acran not just the build directory, but every thing in the npm. and maintain the ability to pull from upstreamm

Comment: now this sounds more like you don't actually want to clone from `git` but rather want to just download the bundled packages from npm and track changes between versions in `git`. Is this more accurate? Otherwise I still don't quite get your question.

Comment: @acran yep this is more accurate, but the issue is how to track the changes between these versions?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your goal now, you want to have a `git` repository of the versions of `threejs` as *released on `npm`*?

As I am not aware of a `git` interface to `npm` this comes to the question *how to track `npm` package versions with `git`?*

For this you would need to create your own `git` repository adding the individual release versions as commits. You may do this by downloading and extracting the verions' tarballs and checking them into `git`, e.g.

```sh
# use dedicated branch for npm versions
git checkout npm
# remove all files
rm -rf *

# download and extract npm version $version
npm view three@$version dist.tarball | xargs curl -L | tar -zx package/ --strip-components=1

# add all files to git and commit
git add -f .
git commit -m "npm version $version"
```

- `npm view three@$version dist.tarball`: gives the direct url to the package archive
- `xargs curl -L`: downloads the archive under the url passed via the pipe
- `tar -zx package/ --strip-components=1`: extracts the `package` director from the archive and strips the first path component (`package/`), i.e. extracts the contents of the directory `package` into the current directory
- `git add -f`: adds all files in the current directory - **even otherwise ignored ones** (`-f`) because the archive may contain a `.gitignore` file ignoring the build files.

This way you can iterate through all (relevant) versions of the `npm` package giving you their diffs in git. You can get a list of all available versions with `npm view three@$version versions`.

If you want to maintain your own edits of the files you can do that on a separate branch

```sh
git checkout private

# do edits
# commit

# merge with latest changes from npm
git merge npm
```

Comment: so to make this clear, when a new version is released in npm I'll need to make a new branch with the new version and then merge it with my "private" branch that has my edits? wouldn't this delete my edits then as the new npm version branch changes are considered newer than my branch edits?

Comment: You should have a branch - say `npm` - that you commit all versions from `npm` to. This branch only needs to be created once. When you fork from this branch with your own edits you can later checkout `npm` again to download and commit a new upstream version to it. When you then `git merge` it into your private branch it will apply all changes since the version you merged from and keep/merge your edits into it - given that this can be done automatically without merge conflicts.